# How to make WebAPI actions accessible only from my app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, security

A common use case for WebAPI would be to have shell views rendered by MVC controllers, which contain javascript that then hit your API to access data.

But let's say you have some expensive API operations and you don't want people remotely accessing those endpoints -- you only want your MVC views, delivered by your application, to access them. How could you go about protecting them?

In this case `Request.IsLocal` doesn't work, because javascript is invoking it from the client's browser on their machine. Even if it did work, you need to dig to get the real `HttpContext` in order to find this property -- and that solution wouldn't work in self-hosted WebAPI.

For API endpoints that require a valid `IPrincipal`, you could protect them with the `[Authorize]` attribute. But what about API endpoints that you want your app to be able to access for anonymous users?

I have tried a solution and will post it separately as an answer, because I'm not sure if it's the best (or even a good) approach.

Answer (score 2):

If your MVC site uses authentication, you could enable forms authentication for your Web API methods. You could write a custom `[Authorize]` attribute that will check for the presence of a forms authentication cookie which will be sent from the AJAX call and if present construct the principal.

Another possible solution is to protect your API with [`tokens`](http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/04/02/making-your-asp-net-web-apis-secure/) which is a more RESTful style. The idea here is that when a user authenticates on your MVC website you could generate and pass a token to the view which will be used when sending the AJAX request to the Web API which in turn will verify the validity of the token and its signature.

If on the other hand your site doesn't use authentication, then things will get very complicated because you have no way of knowing whether the request comes from a trusted client since you are using javascript to call your API methods.

Comment: What if I want the action to be accessible to anonymous users?

Comment: @danludwig - restricting access to an expensive resource and giving an unrestricted access to it are conflicting requirements. You need to make up your mind.

Comment: @danludwig, then things are getting out of control. You simply cannot do that. By the very definition of an anonymous user, it means that he can call any endpoint. And even if you call the Web API only from your controllers and not javascript, the anonymous user could still indirectly call the controller.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov if the user got access to the generated token, don't you think that it can be used outside the application using the token ?

Answer (score 2):

Before you go harping about "what have you tried", here is what I have tried. It works. Just not sure if there is a better way.

1. Create an MVC action filter and add it as a global filter during `Application_Start`.
2. Create an Http (WebAPI) action filter and use it on actions that should reject remote requests.

The global MVC filter does this:

1. Looks for a specific cookie in the request. If the cookie is there, its value is decrypted. The decrypted value should be a string representation of a `DateTime`, so use `DateTime.TryParse` to get it out. If the value is correctly parsed to a `DateTime`, and that `DateTime` is less than a day old, STOP HERE and do nothing else.
2. If the cookie is not there, or cannot be decrypted / parsed, or is older than a day, write a new cookie to the browser. Use the current `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()` as the value, encrypt it, and write it with `HttpOnly = false`.

The WebAPI filter does this:

1. Looks for a specific cookie in the request. If the cookie is there, decrypt its value and try to parse it out as a `DateTime`.
2. If the value is a valid `DateTime` and is less than 2 days old, STOP HERE and do nothing else.
3. Otherwise, throw a 403 Forbidden exception.

A couple of notes about my current implementation of this. First of all, I use AES encryption with a shared secret and a salt. The shared secret is stored as an `appSetting` in web.config. For the salt, I enabled anonymous identification and used `Request.AnonymousID` as the salt. I'm not entirely fond of the salt because it's tricker to get at in a WebAPI controller, but not impossible as long as it is not self-hosted.

Comment: But with this approach, nothing is preventing the client to just grab the cookie and call whatever method on your API he wants. There just isn't a reliable method to prevent access to your Web API from anonymous users and in the same time allow them using your website and your website indirectly calling the Web API.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, this is sort-of true. Note this is not to protect the entire API, just some endpoints that do not require an `IPrincipal`. Also the user would have to grab 2 cookies -- including the .ASPXANONYMOUS, since it is used as the encryption salt. But this does make it more difficult. I will read your tokens link, thanks for that.

Comment: Just for reference, this is called a replay attack, i.e. malicious user is able to successfully resend the request. @danludwig's methodology protects somewhat by making the validity of the request "expire" after a day. However, a day is still a long time; 15 minutes is more typical. You also will generally want to encrypt the request body as well (i.e. the posted fields). That prevents modification of the data, making the replay kind of pointless for most functions.

Comment: @ChrisPratt thanks for the reference. All of our PUT, POST, and DELETE api endpoints are protected with [Authorize], and do require a login. I am using this only on a few GET requests that don't expose private data, just data we don't want to make easy to abuse.