# Asp.Net MVC4 stopping people requesting or posting data to my API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, security

I want to be able to use AJAX to Get/Post to an API controller in my MVC4 application.

However, I don't want anyone to be able to setup a web page and get/post to the controller - only from web pages delivered from my server.

So, should I just use a normal controller and return data, rather than an API controller? (or have I misunderstood that using the API controller opens up the web application to any Get/Post?)

Thanks, Mark

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15366436/304832

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible duplicate of [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15366436/304832). In a nutshell, the only way to secure API endpoints is to have the clients authenticate somehow. This can be done with a normal ASP.NET auth cookie, if you decorate the controllers / actions with the [Authorize] attribute. You could also roll your own solution using API keys or whitelist IP addresses. [See this link](http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/04/02/making-your-asp-net-web-apis-secure/) for a laundry list of options.

The answer I posted to my own question does make it more difficult for non-consumers of my web app to invoke API endpoints, though as Darin points out, it can be circumvented. Users could go to the web app to obtain the encrypted AnonymousID and custom encryption cookie, plug those into Fiddler2 (or any other client), and hit the API as much as they wanted for 24-48 hours.

Comment: Thanks Dan - so the only real way of protecting your app from unwanted Get/Posts - would be to use the antiforgerytoken on the controllers, which would then mean effectively you have to Post and return views - rather than use the API or a normal "not protected by Authentication" controller action?

Comment: It's not the only way. Like the other article referenced, you could whitelist IP addresses if that's feasible. Also, you don't need to return views from POSTs to MVC controllers. You can return JSON or XML from those as well, making them API-ish.

Comment: The app is a car rental system - so could be any member of the public just browsing to see what's available, through to actually renting - I don't want them to have to register, to be able to see what's available.  Thanks again.