# Signing someone into a subdomain using Websecurity / .NET Forms Auth?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

I have an WebApi controller that, when completed, redirects a user from `abc.com` to `subdomain.abc.com`.  The subdomain is on the same application - it's just a different area of the site.  Currently the user has to login again once redirected.  I'd like to essentially copy the cookie with the same credentials over to `subdomain.abc.com`, though I'm not sure if "copying the cookie" is the correct approach.

I'm using forms auth with WebSecurity - typical login looks like this (from a different, *MVC* controller):

```
WebSecurity.Login(user.Username, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe)
```

I'm not trying to cover all subdomains with the same cookie; I'm just trying to programatically log this user into a subdomain one time, from this controller.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but could be risky.

The ideal way to handle this would be to set the domain to .abc.com on your cookie, but as you said, you are not trying to cover all subs with the same cookie.

One way to do it would be to redirect them to a special URL that calls FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie. The problem with that approach is that you are opening up a URL that writes an auth cookie without receiving the actual password.

You could possibly encrypt the username before the redirect, and send it encrypted as a parameter to the URL at subdomain.abc.com, then unencrypt it there before writing the cookie.

**Update after comments**

AFAIK, [you cannot have an `ApiController` that only accepts requests from another `ApiController`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15366436/304832). Same goes for MVC Controllers. Even if you check the `Request.UrlReferer` property in the receiving controller, this is something that could be faked. It is much harder to fake encrypted data when you don't know the encryption cipher.

You are essentially asking how you can hijack authentication in your subdomain from your primary domain. If you do this, you are opening up others to be able to do the same hijacking. Like I said, the ideal solution is to have all domains that share authentication share the same cookie domain. If you don't do that, you are left with either forcing the user to re-authenticate to get a subdomain-specific cookie, or the hijacking scenario. If you go with the hijacking scenario, you can send the username as an encrypted string to the receiving controller, and decrypt it there before invoking `SetAuthCookie`.

Comment: The second approach is interesting but scary.  This is from a WebAPI controller... do you think it would be possible to use `HttpStatusCode.Moved` to redirect the user to this auth controller directly, that only accepts requests from this particular  webApiController?

Comment: You said in your question that it was an MVC controller, are you saying now that you are redirecting from an ApiController in main domain to MVC Controller in sub domain? Or vice versa?

Comment: I'm sorry - I'm mixing the two terms up.  I'm redirecting from a WebApi controller in the base domain, to (presumably) another WebApi controller to handle the `SetAuthCookie`.  The second half could be an MVC controller if you think that's better, though.

Comment: Thank you for the edit.  I've *finally* got this working, except for the last leg of the journey - the redirect.  If you have a moment, any input would be awesome: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20641624/how-to-redirect-from-mvc-post-controller-via-ajax-request